# c++ qualifier error

Tags: c++, constants, qualifiers

I have begun writing some code for a library I need. The following code gives me an error

```
class node {
public:
    node() { }
    node(const node&);
    ~node() { }

    luint getID() { return this->ID; }
    node& operator=(const node&);
protected:
    luint ID;
    std::vector<node*> neighbors;
};
node::node( const node& inNode) {
    *this = inNode;
}

node& node::operator=(const node& inNode) {
    ID = inNode.getID();
}
```

which is the following:

> graph.cpp: In member function 'node&
>   node::operator=(const node&)':
>   graph.cpp:16: error: passing 'const
>   node' as 'this' argument of 'luint
>   node::getID()' discards qualifiers

Did I do anything wrong with the code?

Thanks,

Comment: The following two links might be interessting for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness and http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your operator= function, inNode is constant. The function `getID` is not constant, so calling it is discarding the constness of inNode. Just make getID const:

```
luint getID() const { return this->ID; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `inNode` is declared to be `const`, which means you can only invoke `const` member functions on it. You'll have to add the `const` modifier to `getID` to tell the compiler that it won't modify the object:

```
luint getID() const { return this->ID; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make getID() const.